# No .manager folder inside eclipse installation

Tags: eclipse

There is an issue with eclipse installation, its a new installation and does not open, I am troubleshooting it and was trying to delete thefileTableLocks and found that there is no .manager folder present in the installation.

Ita a MAC machine, OS - El Capitan

My Question is: Does .manager folder always exists in eclipse installation if not in which scenarios it's not present?

Comment: Never hear of a `.manager` folder. Are you sure you are not asking about `.metadata` in the **workspace** which always exists but is a hidden folder on macOS.

Comment: Yes i am sure its .manager inside - configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\.manager

Comment: This will normally be a hidden folder on macOS so Finder won't show it by default.

Comment: I checked there is no hidden folder!